# How to display a day on a given date using an SQL SELECT query in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I'm not much familiar with MySql, since much of the times, I had been working with Oracle. In Oracle, a day [Starting from Monday to Sunday] on a specified date can simply be displayed using the following SQL SELECT query.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('9-AUG-1988','DD-MON-YYYY'),'DAY')FROM DUAL;
```

It shows the day [It can be any starting from Monday to Sunday] on the specified date in the specified format in Oracle. I took some Gooling but I couldn't. How is the same thing achieved in MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(your_date) FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

USING [DAYNAME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) FUNCTION, like:

```
mysql> SELECT DAYNAME('2007-02-03');
        -> 'Saturday'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DAY(DATE_COLUMN_NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```